# On defining a modular arithmetic.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse, euclidean-algorithm

We know how to define $\frac a{a'}\bmod\frac b{b'}$ when $b'=1$, $(a',b)=1$ and $(a,{a'},b)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z_{\neq0}$ holds.

Is there a consistent definition when $b'\in\Bbb Z\backslash\{0,1\}$ holds?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Is it interesting in any way?